# Identify 5-pin IC with "2130A" marking

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I am tearing down a solar lamp PCB and I am curious to identify the components. I am struggling to identify the component U4, which has 2130A written on it.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

HongRun electronics HR2130A battery management IC.

[image]

[Link to datasheet](http://www.horchips.com/data/uploads/2020/05/11/80095eb8b8bc39dc8.pdf)

Comment: Seems to be a curious layout in that case, to me it looks like the Vdd pin isn't connected to a trace. Could be a via sitting underneath the part, I guess.

Comment: @Lundin It runs beneath the IC to the capacitor below it.

Comment: Ah, true, though a bit strange placement of the cap then, as there's plenty of room to place it directly on pin 3.

Comment: @Lundin Indeed.